# Paypal Adaptive Payment fails with unknown error

Tags: java, paypal

I'm working on an Adaptive payment Preapproval call and i'm not sure why, but this is the error i'm getting:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap"><responseEnvelope><timestamp>2013-05-22T08:12:28.087-07:00</timestamp><ack>Failure</ack><correlationId>aa3d68afef688</correlationId><build>5867333</build></responseEnvelope><error><errorId>2010</errorId><domain>CoreRuntime</domain><subdomain>Inbound_Meta_Data</subdomain><severity>Error</severity><category>Request</category><message>Unknown response payload type </message><parameter></parameter></error></ns3:FaultMessage>
```

I have no idea what mistake i did, this code was working a few days ago and in theory, nothing has been changed. I checked in svn history, i have no idea. The errorId 2010 doesn't even show up in the Paypal docs (or i failed to find it).

I'm using the Java sdk. let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was refactoring the properties file reading piece and made a mistake there reading the "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" value, which meant it was empty instead of "NV".